# Calling web service in android

Tags: java, android, .net

I'm calling asmx web service in Android, but every time I run my application I'm getting an error.

```
HTTP request faild.HTTP Status Code : 400
```

I changed the  - to <10.0.2.2:port/WebService1.asmx>

I also tried with

but it's giving the same error.

Service Works perfect in .net but need solution for android.
Kindly Help.
Thank You.

**Code:**

WebService:

```
[WebMethod]
    public string HelloWorld()
    {
        return "Hello World - This is nikki";
    }
```

MainActivity.java

```
import org.ksoap2.SoapEnvelope;
import org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapObject;
import org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapSerializationEnvelope;
import org.ksoap2.transport.HttpTransportSE;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {


 private static final String SOAP_ACTION = "http://tempuri.org/HelloWorld";

    private static final String METHOD_NAME = "HelloWorld";

    private static final String NAMESPACE = "http://tempuri.org/";
    private static final String URL = "http://10.0.2.2:1553/WebService1.asmx";  





@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    call();

}


public void call()
{
     try {

         SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME);

         request.addProperty("passonString", "Rajapandian");

         SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
         envelope.dotNet=true;
         envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);

         HttpTransportSE androidHttpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(URL);
         androidHttpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);

         Object result = (Object)envelope.getResponse();

         Toast.makeText(this, result.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
     } catch (Exception e) {
         Toast.makeText(this, e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
         }
}
```

Comment: http://localhost:1553/WebService1.asmx to http://10.0.2.2:1553/WebService1.asmx...... i also tried with http://192.168.106.4:1553/WebService1.asmx

Comment: Have you declared INTERNET permission in the Manifest?

Comment: yes i have declared internet permission and network state permissions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All webservice calls should be in the background thread.
Android does not allow to call a webservice on the main thread. Use async methods.

Answer (score 0):

`400` means `Bad Request`. The server **is** responding. You're making the HTTP request alright, you're just not following the APIs rules.

Check the documentation. Try dumping the request to the console and see if you're missing headers, misspelling parameters and so on. Also dumping the response body might help your debugging.

Answer (score 0):

```
private void callSubmitWebService() {

    String[] params = new String[7];
    String[] values = new String[7];
    TelephonyManager telephonyManager = (TelephonyManager) getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
    String myAndroidDeviceId = null;

    if (telephonyManager.getDeviceId() != null) {
        myAndroidDeviceId = telephonyManager.getDeviceId();
    } else {
        myAndroidDeviceId = Settings.Secure.getString(getApplicationContext().getContentResolver(), Settings.Secure.ANDROID_ID);
    }

    params[0] = "block_name";
    params[1] = "tab_id";
    params[2] = "department_id";
    params[3] = "username";
    params[4] = "emp_pin";
    params[5] = "image";
    params[6] = "clocked_flag";

    values[0] = "Submit";
    values[1] = myAndroidDeviceId;
    values[2] = selectedID;
    values[3] = searchname;
    values[4] = PinNo;
    values[5] = image.toString();
    values[6] = Status;




    URL = "Your URL";
    Webservice wb = new Webservice(LandingActivity.this, URL,
            params, values);


    Log.e("url callweb()", "" + URL);

    wb.execute();


}
```

**The WbService class is as below**

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;

import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;

import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.entity.UrlEncodedFormEntity;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;

import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;

import org.apache.http.message.BasicNameValuePair;

import android.app.ProgressDialog;

import android.os.AsyncTask;

import android.util.Log;

public class Webservice extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {


    private static String URL;
    private static String params[];
    private static String values[];
    String response = null;
    String id;

    private LandingActivity landingActivity;


    // switch church
    public Webservice(LandingActivity landingActivity,
                      String URL, String params[], String values[]) {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        this.landingActivity = landingActivity;

        this.URL = URL;
        this.params = params;
        this.values = values;


    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {

    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... arg0) {

        response = CallService();

        return response;

    }

    public String CallService() {

        String json = null;
        int responseCode = 0;
        HttpResponse response = null;
        try {
            HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(URL);

            List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();

            int s = params.length;
            Log.e("Params length", "" + s);
            for (int i = 1; i < s; i++) {


                nameValuePairs
                        .add(new BasicNameValuePair(params[i], values[i]));

            }

            httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
            do {

                response = client.execute(httppost);
                responseCode = response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();
                // If you want to see the response code, you can Log it
                // out here by calling:
                // Log.d("256 Design", "statusCode: " + responseCode);
            } while (responseCode == 408);
            BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                    response.getEntity().getContent()));

            json = rd.readLine();
            Log.e("json", "" + json);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            responseCode = 408;
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return json;

    }

protected void onPostExecute(String response) {



    if (values[0].equalsIgnoreCase("Submit"))

    {

        landingActivity.OnGetResponse_for_Submit(response);

    }

}
}
```

**do whatever with responce of the webservice in following function**

```
  public void OnGetResponse_for_Submit(String response) {

}
```